# Get Distinct Values and Latest Record based by date not working. MAX SQL

Tags: php, mysql

HI will need some help in SQL as I want to get the latest data based by date created and all distinct values by products

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT id,productID,productname,onhandqty,MAX(datecreated) AS 'datecreated',endingbalance,incomingqty,soldqty 
FROM inventory 
where status='Added' 
group by productID
```

Here is my Table and Structure:

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l26hB.jpg)

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBtk.jpg)

Here is my output result:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW3e0.jpg)

What I want is unique product ID and get only their latest data based on date created. If I have 3 products with duplicate rows I only want one of them each and its latest datecreated

Comment: When using GROUP BY you can only use aggregation or fields which are in the group by.

Comment: Non-complete GROUP BY. Obtain `MAX(datecreated)` for each `productID` in subquery and join to another table copy.